# SELECT-SQL-Statement - Transformation of a single data record with a date period into several single data records per day

Tags: sql, oracle, time, record, period

I have the following example records in a table that contains records with time periods (Originally import data):

| ID | DateFrom | DateTo | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 03.01.2021 | A |
| 2 | 02.03.2021 | 06.03.2021 | B |
| ... |  |  |  |

The data is imported as individual records into a separate table.

I would like to put the data records into the following form with a SELECT query in order to be able to check in the 2nd step whether all data were imported as a single data record:

| ID | DateFrom | DateTo | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2021 | 01.01.2021 | A |
| 1 | 02.01.2021 | 02.01.2021 | A |
| 1 | 03.01.2021 | 03.01.2021 | A |
| 2 | 02.03.2021 | 02.03.2021 | B |
| 2 | 03.03.2021 | 03.03.2021 | B |
| 2 | 04.03.2021 | 04.03.2021 | B |
| 2 | 05.03.2021 | 05.03.2021 | B |
| 2 | 06.03.2021 | 06.03.2021 | B |
| .. |  |  |  |

Unfortunately, I have a knot in my head and cannot find a query approach.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the hierarchical query suits here. The problem though I still can't fit it in here without using distinct.

This query will work with assummption that "datefrom" and "dateto" columns are of DATE format.
Replace "test_data" with table name you store dates in.

```
select td.id, 
       qq.day_date,
       value
  from test_data td
  join (select distinct id, 
                        datefrom + level - 1 day_date 
                   from test_data 
                connect by level <= (dateto - datefrom + 1)) qq
    on qq.id = td.id
 order by td.id, qq.day_date;
```

If datato and datafrom are just varchars, you may convert them to dates using to_date function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.

I can continue to work with this idea.